# Логирование обращений к объекту

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

Известно, что прямое обращение к параметру это плохо(геттеры и сеттеры рулят), запись из нескольких мест непосредственно в переменную еще хуже.
Но разбирая очередную багу, столкнулся именно с такой ситуацией - имеется контейнер std::map, в который в нескольких(порядка десяти) мест элементы вставляются, и иногда вызывается std::move(точное количество вызовов сказать сложно). И как апофеоз - данный контейнер передается по указателю, и с указателем происходит примерно такая же работа. Интересующий меня элемент вставляется, но в какой-то момент времени исчезает.
Можно ли как-то отлоггировать обращения к данной мапе, не переписывая весь код?
В своих попытках пытался создать отнаследованный от std::map класс, в котором будет вызываться логирование, а после вызов родительского метода. (Не смог одолеть шаблоны, отложил.)
Помню, что адрес любой функции - это местоположение в памяти. И создаваемые объекты имеют адреса.

Итак, **ВОПРОС**: Можно ли написать (а может, уже где-то есть готовая, только о ней не знаю) универсальную обертку, которая будет брать объект(например, создаваемый класс), и при обращении к нему/к его функции с параметрами, будет логировать обращение и вызывать у вложенного в нее объекта соответствующий метод? 
такой своеобразный "человек посередине".
Цель - отследить работу конкретного объекта, не переписывая код во всех местах обращения к нему

Comment: Дебаггеры умеют ставить брейкпоинт на изменение области памяти. Ставите такой на начинку мапы (наверное на счетчик элементов?).

Comment: Скорее всего подобный софт надо не отлаживать, а выбросить и перепиасть заново (без геттеров-сеттеров, но в соответствии с KISS-принципом)

Comment: "Дебаггеры умеют ставить брейкпоинт на изменение области памяти. Ставите такой на начинку мапы (наверное на счетчик элементов?)." - Сейчас как раз под дебаггером (гдб) пытаюсь отлаживаться. Но почему-то, пока не разобрался почему, брекпойнт на двух insert-ах приводит к зависанию отладчика.